# changing partial to full(allow all), full to partial manually, when i will open the app image/video are not loading using uri in android 14.)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, uri, android-14

I have given partial permisssion to image and video  and saved selected file in .txt file, using uri image/video are loading. afterthat changed partial to full(allow all), again full to partial permission  manually, when i will open the app image and video are not loading using uri in android 14.

Expected: changing partial to full(allow all) permission, again full to partial permission changed manually, when i will open the app image and video are should load using uri in android 14.

I have tried to check the uri read permission using checkUriPermission(), this also didn't worked.
Expected: changing partial to full(allow all) permission, again full to partial permission changed manually, when i will open the app image and video are should load using uri in android 14.

Thanks in advance for any help.